# Cannot dereference end list iterator

Tags: c++, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I'm currently working on a project about browser histories.  I'm using the STL's list implementation to keep track of the different websites.  I have most of it figured out but I can't seem to resolve the error:

> Screenshot; cannot dereference end list iterator.

[image: Screenshot; cannot dereference end list iterator.]

The website data is contained within my Site objects.

```
class BrowserHistory {
   private:
      list<Site> history;
      list<Site>::iterator current = history.begin();
   public:
      void visitSite(string, size_t)
      void backButton();
      void forwardButton();
      void readFile(string);
};

void BrowserHistory::visitSite(string x, size_t y)
{
   while (current != history.end()) {
       history.pop_back();
   }
   history.push_back({ x, y });
   current++;
}

void BrowserHistory::backButton()
{
   if (current != history.begin())
       current--;
}

void BrowserHistory::forwardButton()
{
   if (current != history.end())
       current++;
}

void BrowserHistory::readFile(string filename)
{
   string action, url;
   size_t pageSize;
   ifstream dataIn;
   dataIn.open(filename);

   while (!dataIn.eof()) {
       dataIn >> action;
       if (action == "visit") {
           dataIn >> url >> pageSize;
           history.push_back({ url, pageSize });
           current++;
       }
       if (action == "back") {
           current--;
       }
       if (action == "forward") {
           current++;
       }
   }
   dataIn.close();
}
```

Can anyone explain to me what's wrong? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Welcome on SO! Please post the exact error you get. Also explain what attempts you have made to solve the problem.
Btw, your code does not appear to contain any de-referencing of an iterator.

Comment: You should run your program in the debugger and examine the program state at the point where you get this error so you can figure out how the program got into that state ("Why is the iterator at the end?") or whether some piece of code is making an incorrect assumption ("I didn't account for the possibility that the iterator is at the end here.").

Comment: Probably unrelated, but you should give [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons) a read-through.

Comment: Your code is very error prone, as it never checks whether `current` is a valid iterator and/or whether the in- and de-crement operators are possible (you shouldn't de-reference or increment the end iterator, you shouldn't decrement the begin iterator), mind you that for an empty list begin=end.

Comment: `push_back` can invalidate you stored iterator. You can easily replace the iterator with an index.

Comment: In `BrowserHistory::visitSite()` you pop the last entry if this is the current entry? this does not make sense from the name of the function.
In `BrowserHistory::readFile()` you should re-use the functions `visitSite`, `backButton` and `forwardButton`.

Comment: If `current` is a valid iterator, no amount of `pop_back` operations will turn `current` into the end iterator. Use `history.erase(current + 1, history.end())` instead.

Comment: @Walter quoting from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) "If the new size() is greater than capacity() then all iterators and references (including the past-the-end iterator) are invalidated. Otherwise only the past-the-end iterator is invalidated."

Comment: @churill I think you confused `std::list` with `std::vector`. Read the post more carefully before commeting.

Comment: @Walter you are right, I'm sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

When you initialise `current`, the list is empty.
Adding elements to the list does not suddenly make it a valid iterator, even though it will be different from `end`.

It looks like you're thinking of iterators as very much like pointers, but they're not.

Iterators are for iterating and should be considered transient, and not stored for later use.

Use a vector, and use an index for `current` instead of an iterator.

Further, I would rename the "button" functions (what does the history care about *buttons*?) to "goBack" and "goForward" and use your actual interface when reading:

```
void BrowserHistory::readFile(string filename)
{
   ifstream dataIn(filename);
   string action;

   while (dataIn >> action) {
       if (action == "visit") {
           string url;
           size_t pageSize;
           if (dataIn >> url >> pageSize) {
               visitSite(url, pageSize);
           }
           else {
               // Handle error
           }
       }
       else if (action == "back") {
           goBack();
       }
       else if (action == "forward") {
           goForward();
       }
       else {
           // Handle error
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: you edited to implement my suggestions (among other things). Btw, shouldn't if be `goBackward` and `goForward` (for semantic symmetry)?

Comment: @Walter I stuck close to the original, but yes. Or "goBackwards" and "goForwards".